# Interface Type Equivalent in Objective-C?

Tags: java, objective-c

In java I can create an interface:

```
public interface SomeService {
   void test();
}
```

and a class which implements this interface as:

```
public class SomeServiceImpl implements SomeService {
  @Override
  void test() {}
}
```

I my program I could do something like this:

```
SomeService service = new SomeServiceImpl();
service.test();
```

**Is there an equivalent in Objective-C such that I can have an Interface as variable type?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is a protocol

```
@protocol MyProtocol <NSObject>
-(void)test;
@end


@interface MyClass : NSObject <MyProtocol>

@end

@implementation MyClass
-(void) test
{
    ....
}
@end
```

That can be assigned to a variable of type id that should implement MyProtocol

```
id<MyProtocol> obj = [[MyClass alloc] init];
[obj test];
```

But it doesn't have to be id. If you need a view controller that implements a certain protocol, do

```
UIViewController<MyProtocol> *vc = ...
```